# Crud angular using table and dialog from angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to follow the crud method to update fields in my table so I made a method updateLatestProduct but I don't understand something.
I have a dialog with a reactive form

1. how to make that when clicking on a edit a dialog opens with the content of the line

**ts.file**

```
export class ProduitsComponent implements OnInit {

  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Produit>;

  constructor(private produitService: ProduitService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLatestProduct();
  }

  createProduct(product: any) {
    this.produitService.addProduct(product).subscribe((response: Produit) => {
      console.log(response);
      let t = this.dataSource.data;
      t.push(response);
      this.dataSource.data = t;
    });
  }

  updateLatestProduct(product: Produit) {
    this.produitService.updateProduct(product).subscribe(response => {
      this.dataSource.data.splice(product.id);
      console.log(product.id);
    });
  }

  getLatestProduct() {
    let resp = this.produitService.getAllProduct();
    resp.subscribe(result => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Produit>();
      this.dataSource.data = result as Produit[]
    });
  }

  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogFormComponent, {});

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.createProduct(result);
    });
  }
}
```

**dialog.ts**

```
export class DialogFormComponent implements OnInit {

  productForm: any = FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogFormComponent>, 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data:any) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initDialogForm();
  }

  initDialogForm() {
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      name:["" , [Validators.required]],
      price: ["" , [Validators.required]],
      comment: ["" , [Validators.required]],
      date : [""]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.productForm.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the content of the line? Share data? Does it help https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component ?

Comment: @feihoa I give an example if i have one line with name and email i would like click on this line open dialog and in the dialog the content name and email to edit this content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this ?

```html
<mat-table>

  ...

<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
    (click)="openDialog(row)"
></tr> 

</mat-table>
```

```js
openDialog(row: any): void {
  console.log(row);

  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogFormComponent, {
    data: row
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.createProduct(result);
  });
}
```

---

If you want to use your datas into your dialog, then you must initialize your form with the datas :

```js
this.productForm = this.fb.group({
  name:[this.data?.name , [Validators.required]],
  price: [this.data?.price, [Validators.required]],
  comment: [this.data?.comment, [Validators.required]],
  date : [this.data?.date]
});
```

Comment: we are almost there the dialog opens the console.log displays well the content of the lines but the dialog remains empty

Comment: What do you mean by empty ? Could you provide the code of your dialog component ?

Comment: @Richard You have to initilize the form with your data values. Please check my answer